# FlatMapping ListK and Option

Tags: kotlin, arrow-kt

I can't flatmap a `ListKOf<T>` with `T -> Option<V>`.

e.g.

```
listOf(1,2,3).k().flatMap { i ->
  if (i % 2 == 0) Some(i) else None
}
```

Reports `Required (Int) -> ListKOf<Int>. Found (Int) -> Option<Int>`.

To make it compile I need to do this:

```
listOf(1,2,3).k().flatMap { i ->
  val opt = if (i % 2 == 0) Some(i) else None
  opt.toList().k()
}
```

Is it possible to write the function like the former example?

Comment: https://arrow-kt.io/docs/apidocs/arrow-mtl/arrow.mtl.extensions/-list-k-functor-filter/map-filter.html ?

Answer (score 1):

@dyukha's answer above is the most concise way, but to specifically answer your question: `flatMap` operates within a single monadic type; that is, if you want to call `flatMap` on a `List`, you need to return a `List` from the function supplied to `flatMap`; if you want to call `flatMap` on an `Option`, you need to return an `Option` from the function supplied to `flatMap`; etc., etc.  The closest code (without using `.mapFilter()`) is a method that returns a `List` of zero or one elements instead of `Some(x)` or `None`.